# How do I create a "Card" column type in a Microsoft List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, microsoft-lists

I really can use your help on this.  I have decided as part of my efforts to solve a different problem to make a copy of a Microsoft List to a work platform that is not shared as a dashboard and shared area for my company.  I am creating a duplicate List from another List that is the production list so that I can experiment on a duplicate one on my...  Here, a screenshot is worth one hundred words:

[image]

I am using an online presence where my username is part of the URL.  I am doing this as a test to solve a 404 and 403 error I am getting.

To duplicate a List, I have copied the production list to a local EXCEL file; made a table in that file, and used that to upload the data to a new List.  The data types have all been converted to single-line text.  Some of the changes to the data types of the column I am allowed to make.  But for others, I believe I will have to rename and create a new column from scratch with the proper column data type.  I believe I will have to do this with the mysterious "Card" data type.  Can anyone help me with this?

In the List that I am creating from the original, the "Card" data type appears something like this:

[image]

I am sorry that I had to pixelate this pic but the point is that the column for "Card" is nothing more than a single line of text that is the name of a picture file.

On the other hand, the Microsoft List that I am copying FROM has a much more complex class or object for a Card that contains a multitude of data.  It looks something like this:

[image: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/552108i5FB0AD25EC4D9A30/image-dimensions/2500?v=v2&px=-1]

When I click on one of the cards, I get this interesting data window on the side:

[image]

There are many ways to view the data and its various formatting.  I made this quick video about this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFl_mfBirTQ

Please advise.  How do I create a Card class.  There are a couple of paths to take to create a new column but "Card" does not appear on any of these menus:

[image]

Here is another menu of column types.  Which one is a Card type?

[image]

Comment: "Card" column type is not available in SharePoint.

Comment: Agree with Ganesh Sanap, "Card" column type does not exist in the SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a card type.  Selecting the image type creates a display of data for the entire row that appears as if it is a card.